# Project a half-sphere onto a disk to get to cartesian coordinates

Tags: geometry, 3d, stereographic-projections

I guess this is an age-old problem related to making maps of the world BUT

If I have latitude and longitudes of points on a hemisphere and want to get cartesian coordinates on the 2D plane out of that, can I do the following :

- Flatten/press down the half hemisphere into a circle (of which radius ? Such that radial distances to the pole are conserved, or such that area is conserved ? Is direction from the pole always conserved ?)
- Calculate a formula to go from long/lat to polar coordinates centered on the pole (is it a simple proportion ?)
- Go to cartesian from there.

Comment: You can do all you want, but without some further information it's impossible to tell if that makes sense.

Comment: Well already you're telling me is possible, which is a start, and a good one. Now, what further information do you need ?

Comment: You could explain, for instance, why you need to perform that coordinate change.

Comment: Well I have existing code that all works in cartesian. Not going to change all this just for that.

Comment: Existing code to do what?

Comment: Why is that relevant ? My whole program and environment is built with Cartesian coordinates, isn't that enough info ?

Comment: If that is not relevant, then just compute 3D coordinates $(x,y,z)$ of your points and discard $z$ to get 2D coordinates $(x,y)$. Is that fine for you?

Comment: So this would be similar to looking at everything from exactly above the pole. I.e. flattening the half sphere straight down to the base circle. If yes, what are the properties of this projection ? The angle around the pole seems obviously conserved, but what about distance from it ? Or the distance of two points that were at the same latitude i.e. forming a segment that is now orthogonal to a radius of the circle ?

Comment: Guessing no loss for small angular deviations between points, which is definitely my case.